# Deploy same schema to multiple databases using dacpac in azure release pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

1. I have created SQL Database project
2. I have created dacpac file of this project for Azure SQL server
3. I am trying to deploy the same dacpac file to multiple databases
4. I have created Azure Release ( CD ) pipeline
5. I have added SQL Server database deploy task
6. Selected "SQL dacpac" option
7. I need to repeate above steps 100 times in order to deploy to 100 client databases

[image]

**Question **: Is there any better alternative to deploy same schema changes in Azure DevOps to deploy to Azure SQL server
**Note **: I have 100 client DB and 5 env

I am expecting someone to validate above process and provide better alternative or tools , if there is any

Comment: I think what you'd like to do is convert your classic Release to a YAML pipeline. Once that is done then can provide a list of 100 databases and have the pipeline loop through each as opposed to copy and paste/maintain a 100 stages.

Comment: DreadedForest , do we have step for LOOPING ? I could not find one

Comment: There is an [each expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword)

Comment: Hi, I have almost the same need but have 3000+ databases. The list of databases can't be set statically because new databases can be created or existing databases dropped every day. Is there another solution that would not rely on a static list ?